# Simplify (a + b) XOR (c + b)

Tags: c++, bitwise-xor

Is it possible to simplify **(a+b)xor(c+b)**? What is the contribution of **b** to the final result?
Note that I'm mixing boolean algebra with arithmetic, **xor** is a bitwise exclusive or on corresponding bits and **+** is a standard addition on 8 bits, that wraps around when overflown.
a, b, c are unsigned char;

Comment: Unlikely, since XOR is purely bitwise, whereas addition affects adjacent bits.

Answer (score 5):

We can use an SMT solver to test our hypothesis that your formula can be simplified. You can head over to [http://rise4fun.com](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/solve):

```
x = BitVec('x', 8)
y = BitVec('y', 8)
z = BitVec('z', 8)

print simplify((x + z) ^ (y + z))
```

and the result, anticlimactically, is:

```
x + z ^ y + z
```

Which means your formula cannot be further simplified.

Comment: I don't see any hypothesis in the question!

Comment: This result does not make sense `x + z ^ y + z` . Original sum is symmetrical around `x` and `y`, whereas a result is not.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: It does make sense if you consider Python operator precedence, which Z3 uses: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-77

Answer (score 3):

```
(a+b)xor(c+b) 
--------------
=((not(a+b))*(c+b))+((a+b)*(not(c+b))) 
-----------------------
=((not a)*(not b)*(c+b))+((a+b)*(not c)*(not b)) 
----
=((not a)(not b)*c) + (a*(not c)(not b)) 
----
=(not b)((not a)c + a(not c)) 
----
=(not b)(a xor c)
----
```